# I want to find the average in a given array, and find the closest number to that average in java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, average

I want to calculate the number closest to the average of the array, I have finished calculating the average but I have no idea how to find the closest number to that average.

```
public class ClosestToTheArray {
int array [] = new int[]{1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5, 6 ,7 ,8};
int sum;
int sum2;

public void findAverage(){
    double avg;
    double lol = 0;
    double smthelse;
    for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++){
        sum += array[i];
    }
    avg = sum/array.length;
}

public static void main(String [] args){
    ClosestToTheArray test = new ClosestToTheArray();
    test.findAverage();
}
```

}

Comment: `sum` shouldn't be a field in the class. Make it a local variable. (You don't use `sum2`). Also, you'll find that `avg` is always an integer, because you're using integer division.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to delete the sum2, and I can always parse the avg variable, but my qeustion is how to find the number closest to the avg. But thanks for the heads up!

Comment: To find the closest number to that average, calculate the difference from the average using `Math.abs(array[i] - avg)`, and pick the value with the smallest difference.

Comment: can u show all the code sir? array[i] - avg return 3, the average is 4.0, what am I missing here

Comment: `array[i] - avg == 3` when `avg == 4` if `array[i]` is 7. That's the distance of one of the elements from the average; do the same for all other elements (don't forget the `Math.abs`), and find the one with the min difference.

Comment: Can you write the whole code sir?

Comment: Consider an array `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`. It's average is 4.5. What number should the program return? 4 or 5, or both of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the average in the given array and find the number which is closest to the average,

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int array[] = new int[]
    { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    int sum=0;

    double avg;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    avg = sum / array.length;
    System.out.println(avg);
    
    double difference = Math.abs(array[1] - avg);
    Integer closest = array[1];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        double diff = Math.abs(array[i] - avg);
        if(difference > diff)
        {
            difference = diff;
            closest = array[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(closest);
}
```